# JQuery .animate Really Choppy in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome-extension

- I have a JQuery [`.animate`](https://api.jquery.com/animate/) function.
- It switches between two forms.
- It toggles height and opacity.

When the two forms are the same height (and the popup does not resize) the animation is smooth. When the popup has to resize, the animation becomes choppy and a thick black border appears around the popup for a couple of seconds.

Is there anyway of smoothing the animation or should I switch to CSS for my animations?

Right now, the extension is that when a label is clicked a new form appears on top of the old one.

Comment: check line 37 of your code

Comment: @JaromandaX I don't undestand, which line 37 in what file?

Comment: exactly my point

Comment: Please add a code example.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your jQuery animate function uses 2D animations. Look into using 3D translate and transform instead.

Why would 3D be faster than 2D you ask?

Because 3D gets accelerated and rendered using the GPU, 2D does not.

I did the same thing myself not long ago and the results are vastly superior.

Answer (score 0):

It is [2017](http://caniuse.com/#search=transitions). You definitely should switch to CSS transitions.

Answer (score 0):

1) Don't use jQuery in Chrome extensions. It's a browser standardisation framework and you're using it in a component that only works in one browser. Instead use advanced features (such as passive events) that Chrome supports but jQuery does not.

2) Avoid changing the height of elements where that will change the size/position of other elements (or the extension pop-up).

Instead use just `opacity` and `transform` CSS elements on an absolutely positioned element to ensure that the entire animation can be handled by the GPU without reflow.